# how to solve azure cosmos database data fetching issue

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

When I am trying to fetch millions of records of unique or distinct then it throws an error (CosmosHttpResponseError) so which command should I use in Cosmos DB?

Comment: Are you trying to fetch this data via Azure functions? Can you edit the question and paste your piece of code ? What is the average size of each record? What is the throughput setting of your Cosmos DB? Is there some other message with that error which will help debug?

Comment: It's unclear what, exactly, is happening (including your error condition). As already stated in another comment, you'll need to edit your question to provide specifics, such as the queries and code s you're currently executing, along with exact error code. Otherwise, there's really no way to know what's happening.

Answer (score -1):

I would suspect this is your record fetch may be timing out. Even if you consider a 1kb record size, trying to fetch 1000000 records at one go will require approx 2Million RU/S. This is not an efficient way to do things. Maybe you should try paginating through the response [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-pagination) using continuation tokens or perhaps Cosmos is not the best solution for your use case.

Comment: This is simply untrue regarding the number of RU/sec. This isn't how Cosmos DB RU allocation works. You don't need 2 million RU/sec to retrieve a million documents. And the size of the document may or may not even be relevant here, based on what the OP is doing. Aside from that: the OP hasn't shown any code or queries, and they haven't described their collections at all. It's impossible to know what issue they're having, based on the information provided.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be telling the OP that Cosmos DB isn't the best solution for them. That's not for you to decide. But also, you have zero details regarding their queries, data model, or anything else.